# How to display XML string on the ascx page in a grid

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, ascx

I have a object that fetched the xml data stored in db say dataset.xmlcontent .
I want to display all the xmlcontent on the UI , this is a string but because of the xml tags embedded in the data it will not be able to parse the data .

Any input how should I proceed??

code in the model fetches the information here :

`dataSet=orderRepo.GetOrderItemDatas().Where(o => orderItem.Contains(o.OrderItemId)).Select(o=>o).ToList();`

dataSet.Xmlcontent has the XML data stored as string , I am trying to display this on the UI

code in the ascx page :

```
            <tr>
                <th class="ui-state-default">TN</th>
                <th class="ui-state-default">Provisioning Data</th>
            </tr>
            <%
    if (Model.orderdataExist)
    {
        foreach (SomeObject detail in Model.dataSet)
        {
            %>
            <tr >
                <td><%= detail.TN %></td>
                <td><%= detail.Xmlcontent.ToString() %></td>

            </tr>
            <%
        }
    }
            %>

        </table>
```

the output on the UI for this is :

[XML content on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lkdb.png)

How can I parse this XML content to show on the UI ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put into a datatable and then you can bind the table to your page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string xmlResponseFromDb =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                                            "<Table>" +
                                               "<DataRow>" +
                                                    "<TN>6462308635</TN>" +
                                                    "<Provision_Data>6462308635services_options_cosmo_callrecordingasc840</Provision_Data>" +
                                               "</DataRow>" +
                                               "<DataRow>" +
                                                    "<TN>6462308635</TN>" +
                                                    "<Provision_Data>6462308635services_options_cosmo_callrecordingascspeechanalytics840</Provision_Data>" +
                                               "</DataRow>" +
                                            "</Table>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponseFromDb);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("TN", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Provision_Data", typeof(string));

            foreach (XElement row in doc.Descendants("DataRow"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { (string)row.Element("TN"), (string)row.Element("Provision_Data") });
            }

        }
    }

}
```